# How to check that how much data transfer between client & server during partial postback?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

is there any tool by which i can check how much data transfer between client & server during partial post back. i hard firebug could help this regarding this matter. i never use firebug so please someone tell me how to check that how much data transfer between client & server during partial post back with the help of firebug or any other tool during partial post back.
please guide me in detail. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Network Monitoring](http://getfirebug.com/network) in FireBug.